# Wait end of two subscribe to make an operation

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have two subscribe like this :

```
this.birthdays = await this.birthdaySP.getBirthdays();
this.birthdays.subscribe(groups => {
    const allBirthdayT = [];
    groups.map(c => {
      allBirthdayT.push({
        key: c.payload.key, 
        ...c.payload.val()
      })
    })

    console.log(allBirthdayT);
});

this.birthdaysInGroups = await this.birthdaySP.getBirthdaysInGroups();
this.birthdaysInGroups.subscribe(groups => {
    const allBirthdayB = [];
    groups.map(c => {
      c.birthdays.subscribe(d => {
        d.map(e => {
          allBirthdayB.push(e);
        })
      })
    })

    console.log(allBirthdayB);
});
```

I would like to wait the end of this two subscribes to compare allBirthdayB and allBirthdayT arrays (i receive datas in two console.log).

*this.birthdaySP.getBirthdays()* and *this.birthdaySP.getBirthdaysInGroups()* are two observable that receive data from firebase.

The first Observable is like that :

```
async getBirthdays() {
   const user = await this.authSP.getUserInfo();
   return this.angularFire.list('birthdays', ref => ref.orderByChild('creator_user_id').equalTo(user.uid)).snapshotChanges();
}
```

I try with forkJoin but i don't know how i can use it to solve this problem

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `combineLatest()` function.

Example:

```
combineLatest(observable1$, observable2$)
    .subscribe(([observable1, observable2]) => {
        console.log(observable1, observable2);
    });
```